# Grab keyboard on XEmbed window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, x11

I'm trying to migrate [open source application](https://github.com/devqore/myrdp) written in PyQt4 to Qt5 (PyQt5 or PySide2) and I have a problem with migration of `QtGui.QX11EmbedContainer` to Qt5. It looks that XEmbed container created with `QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer` cannot grab keyboard properly.

In Qt4 it was possible to grab keyboard in such way (for simplicity I'll attach `xterm`):

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


def clientEmbed():
    container.grabKeyboard()
    print("Keyboard grabbed")


def clientClosed():
    container.releaseKeyboard()
    print("Keyboard released")


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
container = QtGui.QX11EmbedContainer(mainWidget)
container.clientIsEmbedded.connect(clientEmbed)
container.clientClosed.connect(clientClosed)

vBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
vBoxLayout.addWidget(container)
mainWidget.setLayout(vBoxLayout)

process = QtCore.QProcess(container)
winId = container.winId()
mainWidget.show()

process.start("xterm", "-into {} -xrm xterm*.allowSendEvents:true".format(winId).split())

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this case any key event was sent to `xterm`, but in Qt5 analogous code doesn't work properly and `xterm` doesn't receives any key events:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


def processStarted():
    container.grabKeyboard()
    print("Process started")


mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
mainWidget.showMaximized()
window = QtGui.QWindow()
container = QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(window, mainWidget)
vBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vBoxLayout.addWidget(container)
mainWidget.setLayout(vBoxLayout)
mainWidget.show()
winId = int(window.winId())

process = QtCore.QProcess(container)
process.started.connect(processStarted)
process.start("xterm", "-into {} -xrm xterm*.allowSendEvents:true".format(winId).split())

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At this time I'm considering migration from Qt4 to GTK3 which plays nice with grabbing keyboard on XEmbed, but it will be more time consuming. For example analogous working code in PyGTK:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
from subprocess import Popen


def plugged_added(plugged_socket):
    Gdk.Seat.grab(seat, plugged_socket.get_window(), Gdk.SeatCapabilities.KEYBOARD, True)
    print("xterm attached")


def plugged_removed(plugged_socket):
    Gdk.Seat.ungrab(seat)
    print("xterm detached")


seat = Gdk.Display.get_default().get_default_seat()
window = Gtk.Window(title="Xterm embed")
socket = Gtk.Socket()
window.add(socket)
sock_id = str(socket.get_id())
socket.connect("plug-added", plugged_added)
socket.connect("plug-removed", plugged_removed)

cmd = ["xterm", '-xrm', "xterm*.allowSendEvents: true", "-into", sock_id]
Popen(cmd)
socket.show()
window.show()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

So does anybody have idea how to achieve grabbing keyboard in Qt5 like it is possible in Qt4 or PyGTK3? I'm also opened to solutions including `xlib`, `xcb` etc.